# MyDoggyMultiSplitContentManagerUI :adding tab in sequence

Tags: java, swing, docking

I already added a component to `ToolWindowManager` using `MyDoggyMultiSplitContentManagerUI`.

But when i add 2nd component to `ToolWindowManager`, it added below the 1st component.Now I want to add the 2nd component next to 1st just like `JtabbedPane` using `MyDoggyMultiSplitContentManagerUI`.

Test Code :

```
public class App extends JFrame
{   
    App()
    {
        MyDoggyToolWindowManager myDoggyToolWindowManager;
        ToolWindowManager toolWindowManager;

        myDoggyToolWindowManager = new MyDoggyToolWindowManager();
        toolWindowManager = myDoggyToolWindowManager;

        toolWindowManager.getContentManager().setContentManagerUI(new MyDoggyMultiSplitContentManagerUI());
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            toolWindowManager.getContentManager().addContent("Test"+i, "Test1", null, new JButton("Test"+i));
        }
        toolWindowManager.getContentManager().setContentManagerUI(new MyDoggyMultiSplitContentManagerUI());
        add(myDoggyToolWindowManager);
    }   

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        App frame=new App();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Screenshots: This is the output from the code.

[image: this is the output from the code]

But I want something like this.

[image: But I want something like this]

Comment: We wont know anything about your implementation until you show us your code.

Comment: Please check the code. @ krishna

Comment: You want a `JTabbedPane`?

Comment: @trashgod No , I am using MyDoggyMultiSplitContentManagerUI . You can see in screeshots what i want.